# What kind of econometric analysis can be used on Indian domestic petroleum sales 2008-2018?

Tags: applied-econometrics, time-series, energy-economics, firm, autoregressive

I have data for sales of petroleum products across different states in India of both public sector and private sector companies for 10 years.

Number of years: 2008 to 2018 monthly data (10 years)
Number of petroleum products: 47
Number of states: 35
Number of companies: 14 (11 in public sector, 3 in private sector)

What type of econometric analysis can be conducted on this data? I would like to use [vector autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) (VAR). Can any ideas be suggested? How can I use VAR and in establishing what relationship?

Comment: International corner building. Burning petroleum and other fossil carbon has so vast advantages for vegetable plant growth that the attitudes and regulations will change in a way that increases sales.